# MySQL query not returning results if more than 2 tables specified

Tags: mysql, select, centos, cpanel

I have this very simply MySQL query which is working fine on one server setup.

```
SELECT *, o.status AS st, o.token AS tk, o.datetime AS dt
FROM p_orders o, p_courses c, p_orders_payments p
```

I've transferred the site/database to a different server (same data and structure etc) and everything works apart from the above query.  Well, it works but it returns zero results.  If I remove the last part `p_orders_payments p` then it returns results, it's almost like it can't select more than 2 tables at once.

Is there a setting somewhere that I'm overlooking which prevents this?

Original server was a self configured CentOS box, the new server is a clients CPanel account.

Comment: Sounds like the `p_order_payments` table is empty. You're asking for a cross-product of all the tables, and when you cross with an empty table you get nothing.

Comment: This may be what's happening.

Comment: This query is pretty perverse. Shouldn't there be a join condition between the tables. E.g. the row for an order should only show payments for that order, not all other payments.

Answer (score 0):

Barmars' comment is correct. `p_order_payments` for some reason was empty.